# How to access R session/global environment after running script through Rscript on Linux

Tags: r, linux, rscript

I am using a Linux Workstation to run my R script. I did so using `screen` and then `Rscript myRscript.R`. Is there anyway to access the R session after the script has run? I want to be able to write new commands and access the global environment that was created during that session.

I tried asking the Unix community, but no response...
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608073/how-to-pass-code-to-attached-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is lost after the script is done running. But you can save the environment using `save.image("env_file.Rdata")` and use it later using `load("env_file.Rdata")`.

See http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/base/html/save.html

Comment: My script did not make it to the end, something went wrong along the way. Do you know if ```Rscript --save myRscript.R``` would save the workspace where ever it stops even if it does not make it to the end of the script?

Comment: I don't think it would save the workspace if there's an error. If you want to debug the script, maybe can use the R console instread of`source("myscript.R")` and then use `save.image`. Or maybe using `Rscript -e "tryCatch({source('myRscript.R')}); save.image('env_file.Rdata')"` to use tryCatch to handle any error and save the environement image anyway.